# Serializable simple Object IOException

Tags: java, android, ioexception, serializable, objectoutputstream

**Found the solution:**
you have to open the Streams like this:

```
FileInputStream  inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

Same with Output. This fixed it for me, should anyone stumble upon this in search for an answer.

**Original question:**
Through a few tests with `Toast`s I have found that when I call the Constructor for `ObjectOutputStream` I get an `IOException` thrown.

My code looks like this. Note that this is merely a test project, and I can't even get this one to work.

```
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("write");
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                File f = new File("Filepath");
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.createNewFile();
                }

                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(f)); //IOException here!

                Series x = new Series("Test", 20, 12);
                // oos.writeObject(x);

                oos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Not read anything yet!");

    Button r = new Button(this);
    r.setText("Read");
    r.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(new File("Filepath")));
                Series y = (Series) ois.readObject();
                tv.setText(y.getName() + "-" + y.getNumOfSeason() + "-"
                        + y.getNumOfEpisode());
                ois.close();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem seems to be my constructor call. Before I added the part with

```
if (!f.exists()) {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
```

I got a `FileNotFoundException`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution:**
you have to open the Streams like this:

```
FileInputStream  inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

Same with Output. This fixed it for me, should anyone stumble upon this in search for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excerpt of the Oracle documentation for [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does
>   not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other
>   reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

In your case, I think that the file is treated as a directory since it has no extension, so the exception is thrown.

Comment: I added an extension, still getting FNFE thrown.

Comment: @AdrianJandl, I was just making assumptions, you gotta investigate your issue based on the cases that the documentation mentions. Are you sure that there's nothing preventing the file from being created or opened?

Answer (score 0):

A FileNotFoundException is thrown when program doesn't find the file in disk or wherever you are trying to access the file.
Check your file path and try again.

Comment: I avoided the `FileNotFoundException` by checking if the file exists and if it doesn't creating it. I get an IOException at my Constructor call from OOS.

Comment: The same, you are avoiding the FileNotFoundExecption but you are getting the IOException after. Are you sure about your file path?

Comment: I just put a string instead of my Filepath that says "test". Still getting the FileNotFoundException.
Should it not be created when I open the Stream?

Comment: Test with a real file, put it in C:/ for example and make the File constructor refer to it by File f = new File("C:/yourFile.txt");

Comment: I am testing this on my phone. Should it not work just by using a `String` with the `File` Constructor?

Comment: Well, I don't think so, if you don't provide with a path to your file (either full path or relative path) you will fail to an IOException anyway (either FNF exception or IO one)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but i think you can try using a formatter, the formatter creates the file if it does not exist.

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter (file);
```

I hope it helps.